# Pyspark sort dataframe by expression

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently reading `Spark the definitive guide` and there is an example to `orderBy` the DataFrame by using an `expr` but it does not work:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Row

schema = StructType([
  StructField("origin", StringType(), True),
  StructField("destination", StringType(), True),
  StructField("count", LongType(), True)
])

rows = [
  Row("US", "Germany", 5),
  Row("US", "France", 1),
  Row("US", "UK", 10)
]

parallelizedRows = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows)
df = spark.createDataFrame(parallelizedRows, schema)
```

Now, in order to sort the DataFrame in `descending` order using `expr`,

```
df.orderBy(expr("count desc")).show(3)
```

The output is still in `ascending`. But it works using `Column` class:

```
df.orderBy(col("count").desc()).show(3)
```

Any idea why `expr` isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working in a sandbox environment, such as a notebook, try the following:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

f.expr("count desc")
```

This will give you

```
Column<b'count AS `desc`'>
```

Which means that you're ordering by column `count` aliased as `desc`, essentially by `f.col("count").alias("desc")`.
I am not sure why this functionality doesn't exist in `expr()`, but I believe it's because you have several other options to do this anyway, such as:

```py
df.orderBy(f.col("count").desc())
df.orderBy(f.col("count"), ascending=False)
df.orderBy(f.desc("count"))
```

Each of which will return something along the lines of:

```
>>> f.desc("count")
Column<b'count DESC NULLS LAST'>
```

That being said, if you register your `DataFrame` as a table a run a `sqlContext.sql(...)` query against it, you'd be able to run an `ANSI SQL` query, with `ORDER BY COUNT DESC;` at the end and it will work.

As a side note, please try not to use `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` for two reasons:

1. It's never a good idea to import everything from a module if you can import the module under alias
2. In this specific case, you're importing stuff like `pyspark.sql.functions.sum` as `sum` which overrides native python library functions, leading to annoying and hard-to-debug errors in your code later down the line.